# String Object File instead of the actual object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

So I am actually trying to give my my property named : ModalFile the object for any file to upload. Instead of receiving the object as normal I am receiving a string named "File" and when I click on it, it says ""[object File]". I have seen some people who told to give the parameter $event as a parameter to fix this but It didn't solve my problem.

```js
export default {
  name: 'Marketplace',
  data() {
    return {
      ModalFileName: null,
    };
  },
```

```js
    onFileSelected(event) {
      const data = event.target.files[0];
      this.ModalFileName = data;
    },
```

```html
<input class="file-input" type="file" name="resume" @change="onFileSelected($event)">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing file object inside `ModalFileName` variable. Try this:
`event.target.files[0].name`

## Working snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      ModalFileName: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.ModalFileName = event.target.files[0].name;
      console.clear();
      console.log(this.ModalFileName)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<input id='app' class="file-input" type="file" name="resume" @change="onFileSelected" />
```

Comment: Thank you but normaly the file would be named ModalFile and would contain all event.target.files[0] informations and property but I have a small with eslint. Now I just want all of these property but instead I have "[object File]"

Comment: Normaly I am suppose to do this. ```js this.ModalFileName = event.target.files[0]``` but I got this eslint problem also.. ESLint: Use array destructuring.(prefer-destructuring)

Comment: if you store `this.ModalFileName = event.target.files[0]` then your file name would be `this.ModalFileName.name`. You also get all other properties inside `this.ModalFileName`. For Esline problem. You can ignore the line using `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: Thanks also I solve my issue by changing null components data to empty string.